# Number conversion in haskell

Tags: haskell

The following code gives me an error which is somehow related to any type conversion issue:

```
testfn:: Float -> Integer
testfn n = 4.99 * fromIntegral(ceiling(n * (1.0/4.0)))

calculate_price:: Float -> Integer
calculate_price n = testfn(n)

main = do 
    print(calculate_price 3)
```

I'm new to haskell and I do not really understand why a multiplication is such a pain. The error is the following when I compile with ghc:

```
• No instance for (Fractional Integer)
    arising from the literal ‘4.99’
• In the first argument of ‘(*)’, namely ‘4.99’
  In the expression: 4.99 * fromIntegral (ceiling (n * (1.0 / 4.0)))
  In an equation for ‘testfn’:
      testfn n = 4.99 * fromIntegral (ceiling (n * (1.0 / 4.0)))
```

|
2 | testfn n = 4.99 * fromIntegral(ceiling(n * (1.0/4.0)))
  |            ^^^^

Comment: `4.99` is not an `Integral`...

Comment: Your `testfn` doesn't return an `Integer` type in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

In Haskell operations of the `Num` class like multiplication are defined as [**`(*) :: Num a => a -> a -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-42-). That means that the two operands and the result all have the same type.

By writing `4.99 * fromIntegral …` you thus say that `4.99` and `fromIntegral …` and the result (an `Integer` according to your signature), should be the same. So the compiler derives that `4.99` should be an `Integer`, but `4.99` is not a literal that can be a `Integer`. Since it has a decimal dot, it should be of a type taht is a member of the [**`Fractional`** type class](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Fractional).

It is likely that you simply do not want the result to be an `Integer`, since multiplying with `4.99` is rather non-sensical if the result should be an `Integer`. You can for example use `Float`:

```
testfn :: Float -> Float
testfn n = 4.99 * fromIntegral (ceiling (n / 4.0))
```

The `calculate_price` is just the same as `testfn`:

```
calculate_price :: Float -> Float
calculate_price = testfn
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember the hierarchy of `Num` Typeclass:

```
             Num a
             /   \  
            /     \ 
           /       \
  (Fractional a)  (Integral a)
      /   \           /   \  
     /     \         /     \ 
    /       \       /       \
 Double   Float   Integer   Int
```

And all this functions are from Num:

```
(+), (*), abs, signum, fromInteger, (negate | (-))
```

In your case:

```
(*) :: Num a => a -> a -> a
```

As you can see, `a -> a -> a`  means all of the same type, so:

```
testfn n = 4.99 * fromIntegral (ceiling (n / 4.0))
```

You can see:

```
4.99 :: Float

*

fromIntegral(ceiling(n * (1.0/4.0))) :: Integral a => a
```

And there is the error, you cannot apply `*` to different types.